# Strace : ERRORS in access

Tags: command-line

I am running an executable (of c program) with strace command and get the following output. Please help me out why does it gives error in access and also this whole process gets killed at the end?

Please give me some direction that what can be the potential reasons behind this.

[image]

Comment: If you don't show us that C program, nobody can't determine where the problem is.

Comment: General programming questions should be asked on stackoverflow instead of askubuntu.  I can tell you that you are barking up the wrong tree: access() just lets the program know whether it has access to a file or not, it does not kill it.  Also I'd bet that if you have a look at `dmesg` you will see that the out of memory killer killed the program for hogging too much memory.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that your program calls `brk(2)` so many times (8843) leads me to think that your code is requesting too much memory from the system. And generally, on Linux, when a program requests too much memory, it is killed with `SIGKILL`.

### More details

`brk(2)` is one of the two ways a program has to request memory. The other way is `mmap(2)`. The `malloc(3)` and friends implementations offered by the GNU C Library use a mix of the two.

Generally speaking, whatever way your program allocates memory, Linux does not complain. Even if no memory is available, it is possible that the kernel still return valid addresses.

That's because Linux allocates memory *lazily*, in the sense that memory is not "physically allocated" until you start using it. This is a great performance optimization.

Now, what happens when you try to use some memory, but your system's RAM and swap are full? If Linux has allocated your memory physically, then there are no problems. Else, a component called *OOM killer* starts killing processes that consume most of the memory, with the aim of keeping the system usable.

### About access

You noted that `strace -c` is reporting 4 `access(2)` failures. This is surely not a symptom of a problem. It is perfectly fine for a system call to fail. Problems occur when your program does not handle failures.

An example:

```
$ strace -e trace=stat -- ls /abc 
stat("/abc", 0x1df2e30)                 = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
ls: cannot access /abc: No such file or directory
+++ exited with 2 +++
```

I've told `ls` to list the contents of a non-existent directory (`/abc`), therefore the call to `stat(2)` has failed with `ENOENT`. This is not a problem for `ls` itself: it has detected the failure and displayed an error message.

Problems would have occurred if `ls` didn't check the return value of `stat(2)`.

**About your specific problem:** it's difficult to know why access has failed. The output of `strace -e trace=access` or `strace -C` would give you some hits. However I firmly believe that such failures are not a problem for you, as they probably come from the GNU C Library:

```
$ strace -e trace=access -- ls
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
```